# Get Max(id) from one to many table

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I know this question was asked many times but I was tring and trying without success

I have `one to many` relationship between two tables and some more `inner-joins` to get more data.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT     
    ShopOffer.OfferID, 
    ShopOffer.OfferMessage,     
    Shop.ID,                             
    Shop.Name,           
    Shop.Phone, 
    [User].Name,            
    [User].UserID, 
    ShopOfferStatus.Name AS StatusName,     
    BlockedShopInUser.IsBlocked

FROM         
    ShopOffer 
    INNER JOIN ShopOfferStatus ON ShopOffer.ShopOfferStatusID = ShopOfferStatus.ShopOfferStatusID 
    INNER JOIN Shop ON ShopOffer.ShopID = Shop.ShopID 
    INNER JOIN UserRequest ON ShopOffer.UserRequestID = UserRequest.UserRequestID 
    INNER JOIN [User] ON UserRequest.UserID = [User].UserID 
    INNER JOIN BlockedShopInUser ON Shop.ShopID = BlockedShopInUser.ShopID AND [User].UserID = BlockedShopInUser.UserID
```

Each shop can create many offers. In that query I would like to get only the last offer for each shop.

Thanks.

Comment: And do you mind telling us how can we know what's the last offer of a shop?, what column defines which offer came first?

Comment: sorry, it's:  'ShopOffer.OfferID' (identity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to start with `Shop` and then perform a `CROSS APPLY` on the `TOP 1` record from `ShopOffer`:

```
SELECT     
    ShopOffer.OfferID, 
    ShopOffer.OfferMessage,     
    Shop.ID,                             
    Shop.Name,           
    Shop.Phone, 
    [User].Name,            
    [User].UserID, 
    ShopOfferStatus.Name AS StatusName,     
    BlockedShopInUser.IsBlocked

FROM Shop
    CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT TOP 1 OfferID, OfferMessage, ShopOfferStatusID, UserRequestID
       FROM ShopOffer AS s
       WHERE s.ShopID = Shop.ShopID 
       ORDER BY s.OfferID DESC
    ) ShopOffer
    INNER JOIN ShopOfferStatus ON ShopOffer.ShopOfferStatusID = ShopOfferStatus.ShopOfferStatusID 
    INNER JOIN UserRequest ON ShopOffer.UserRequestID = UserRequest.UserRequestID 
    INNER JOIN [User] ON UserRequest.UserID = [User].UserID 
    INNER JOIN BlockedShopInUser ON Shop.ShopID = BlockedShopInUser.ShopID AND [User].UserID = BlockedShopInUser.UserID
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
;WITH LastShopOffer AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ShopID ORDER BY OfferID DESC)
    FROM ShopOffer
)
SELECT     
    SO.OfferID, 
    SO.OfferMessage,     
    S.ID,                             
    S.Name,           
    S.Phone, 
    U.Name,            
    U.UserID, 
    SOS.Name AS StatusName,     
    B.IsBlocked
FROM (  SELECT * 
        FROM LastShopOffer
        WHERE RN = 1) SO
INNER JOIN ShopOfferStatus SOS 
    ON SO.ShopOfferStatusID = SOS.ShopOfferStatusID 
INNER JOIN Shop S
    ON SO.ShopID = S.ShopID 
INNER JOIN UserRequest UR
    ON SO.UserRequestID = UR.UserRequestID 
INNER JOIN [User] U 
    ON UR.UserID = U.UserID 
INNER JOIN BlockedShopInUser B
    ON S.ShopID = B.ShopID 
    AND U.UserID = B.UserID;
```